# expect not able compile regular expression pattern:

Tags: expect

I am running expect from Jenkins job and it is giving below mentioned error. 
Not sure what is wrong in code, I am fairly new with expect. Appreciate help!

Error Message:

```
send: sending "date\r" to { exp3 }
couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid
while executing
"expect -re "*2016*" "send_user ""
```

Expect Code:

```
   #!/usr/local/bin/expect
    exp_internal 1
    set timeout 20
    spawn ssh USER_ID@Server_ID
    expect "*assword:" {send "password\\r"}
    expect -re "Login (incorrect|invalid)" {send_user "\nlogin failed\n" }
    expect -re "Last login:*" {send_user "\nlogin successful\n" }
    send "cd some_directory\\r"
    send "pwd\\r"
    expect -re "some_directory" {send_user "\n-->location verified\n"}
    send "date\\r" 
    expect -re "*2016*" {send_user "\ndate verified\n"}
```

Comment: `*` is a regex metacharacter that means zero-or-more of the preceding element. `*2016*` has the leading `*` without and preceding elements. That's not legal. You meant `.*2016.*` or, better` just `2016`.

Comment: Otherwise, remove the `-re`, thereby making the pattern to behave as a glob pattern.